# discord.js Cannot read property 'guild' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've already looked through a few tutorials and pages, but couldn't find a working version to check whether the author has the appropriate role.

My last tryed code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {
  token
} = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();

//functions
function loadServer() {
  server = getJ('./server.json');
}

function abnahme(message){
let charRole = message.guild.roles.find("name", "Character-Abnehmer");

if (message.content == 'accepted' && message.member.roles.has(charRole)) {
//code....
}else {
        return;
      }
}

//run

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
});

//events
loadServer();
client.on('message', message => {      
if (message.content.startsWith(server.prefix)) {

const args = message.content.slice(server.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    message.channel.send(`\`command: ${command} args: ${args}\``);

      if(command == 'abnahme'){
        abnahme(message);
      }
  }

});

client.login(token);
```

Can someone give me an example of how I can just query the role?

Comment: Unless something else is calling `abnahme()` or this is in some way different from the code producing the error, I don't see how this code could produce that error.  If `message` were `undefined` when calling `abnahme(message)` then the lines before that would have failed with the same error.

Comment: I don't think the error in the title is coming from this version of your code (especially because you mentioned this is the last one you tried). There are lots of small errors in your code but you should make sure you're describing the actual problem you have. Are you using discord.js version 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to see if a member has a role is with [GuildMember.roles.cache.has()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles).

Use this code

```js
client.on('message', async msg => {
let memberHasRole = msg.member.roles.cache.has('role-id');
//true if member has the role, false if they don’t
})
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined,  I think the code in front of it contains errors but thanks